# FAB - square on pre Lollipop and without shadow on Lollipop

Tags: android, floating-action-button, android-design-library

It looks like `FloatingActionButton` is not working ether on Android 4.0 and Lollipop. As you can see on image below, on Android Lollipopo shadow is missing and on Android 4.1.1 it's square :/

Anyone faced this issue?

Library version:
`compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'`

Code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/abc_ic_clear_mtrl_alpha"/>
```

[image]

Comment: There's one reported issue with somewhat similar behaviour ; https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=175067 .

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Thanks to @harism comment, simply setting `app:borderWidth="0dp"` resolve both issues.

Note: don't forget to add `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` to your root layout.

Comment: i still see that its a sqaure on lollipop devices also. Am i missing something.  `<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_width="56dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:id="@+id/fab_1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"/>`

Comment: Note tested it on nexus 5 which has 5.1 running

Comment: This was fixed in v22.2.1. if you are still having issues, make sure you are aren't setting the background color directly, just the tint.

Answer (score 5):

If the FAB still appears as square after setting borderWidth to 0dp, make sure that you aren't setting android:background in your XML or calling setBackgroundColor in code.

You should use android:backgroundTint (XML) or setSupportBackgroundTintList (code)

Answer (score 4):

@Raghunandan, I have same problem on Lollipop also.
Finally I find that the root cause is a drawable named "fab_background" in my drawable folder.
The drawable is previously used for my own fab implementation.
Now I can see round fab after I rename this drawable.

Answer (score 3):

Setting
app:borderWidth="0dp"
works. But if you are getting rendering issues in Android studio and have the Renderer set to Android M or 22, set it to 21

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a bug. A developer said "Fixed internally. Will be out soon.".