# FloatingActionButton, square button below API level 17

Tags: android, material-design, android-design-library

I am using android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton from the new Design Support library 22.2.0, in my layout file. It is working fine but it shows a square button below API level 17

[image: API 16]

Comment: Does that mean new design support library is not useful for FAB button below  API 17 ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [FAB - square on pre Lollipop and without shadow on Lollipop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30538604/fab-square-on-pre-lollipop-and-without-shadow-on-lollipop)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is known by Google and will be fix soon in the next version of the Design Support Library, see this issue: [FAB Appears as a square on API 16](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=175067). It should only concern API 16.

The workaround, proposed in the same thread, is to add `app:borderWidth="0dp"` to your FAB.

Answer (score 6):

Finally the issue has been fixed in the new release

```
  compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
```

this will solve the square layout issue in API 16.
FAB performs well if you place it inside Coordinate Layout.
Check out https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list?can=1&q=label:Version-22.2.1 for issues and fixes in new version.

Answer (score 2):

**Released version 22.2.1** This release contains bug fixes related to FAB

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=175067

Change your gradle

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
```

Install support repository revision 16. So you can avoid the workaround [app:borderWidth="0dp"]

Answer (score 1):

If it helps, I solved my issue by removing

```
android:background
```

It was a remnant from the previous FAB library I used. The design library's gets the color automatically from `colorAccent`.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following attribute to the xml floating button

```
app:borderWidth="0dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

use different library projects which supports floating action button below API level 17 . you can find easily here .plz refer this .

[Floating Action Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24605116/floating-action-button-for-lower-version)