# Plus Icon in Floating Action Button not rendered correctly in Android pre-Lollipop

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I tried to setup a fab by using the support design library.

Code in XML:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_18dp"
    app:borderWidth="2dp"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    android:onClick="submit"
    app:rippleColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

</android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton>
```

On Nexus 6(lollipop), the plus icon is rendering correctly.

[image]

But on nexus 4(pre lollipop), plus icon size is crossing the circle.

[image]

I have downloaded and used the plus(ic_add_white_18dp) from [Material icons](https://www.google.com/design/icons/index.html)

Icon Sizes used:

```
mdpi - 18dp
hdpi - 27dp
xdpi - 36dp
xxdpi - 54dp
```

[image]

**What should be the correct size to use for plus icon.**

Comment: For some odd reason I do not see the "plus" on the material icons anymore. Where did you find it?

Comment: please search with text "add" and you can find icons under "Content" section

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Update

This has been fixed as of v22.2.1.

---

As it was stated on [FloatingActionButton, square button below API level 17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30635908/floatingactionbutton-square-button-below-api-level-17)

Which referenced this bug: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=175067

Your FAB should have `app:borderWidth="0dp"`