# Floating Action Button is changed to square in Shape

Tags: android, api, floating-action-button

No, this is not a duplicate question. [seems to be duplicate link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30635908/floatingactionbutton-square-button-below-api-level-17).That is the question that solved the issue of FAB in square which is below `<API 16`. But here in API 16.,It is working.Only the above,that mean API 21,it is in ***SQUARE***.

I have implemented a Floating Action Button.Initially it was circle in shape.Later I changed its background color using,

**app:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_green_dark"**  even I tried

**app:borderWidth="0dp"** to get in Circle in shape.But these way didn't help me.

***In API 16 it is working nice. Only an issue in API 21.***

***xml:***

```
  <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/cartfab1"
            style="@style/Layout_ww"
            android:layout_above="@+id/txt_categoryName"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_shopping_cart"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:borderWidth="0dp" />
```

Comment: Updated.Please check it.

Comment: @appukrb it is working nice in API 16.Above 16 only it is not working good.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30538604/fab-square-on-pre-lollipop-and-without-shadow-on-lollipop, post `xml` of FAB

Answer (score 1):

In your `layout`

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/fab_rounded"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

In your `values/styles.xml`

```
<style name="fab_3_rounded">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">50%</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeTopLeft">20dp</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeTopRight">20dp</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeBottomLeft">20dp</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeBottomRight">20dp</item>
</style>
```

This will give you a rounded, set `cornerSizeTopLeft`, `cornerSizeTopRight`, `cornerSizeBottomLeft` and `cornerSizeBottomRight` and adjust them to the size you want. If you want square change it to 0dp for each section

Answer (score -2):

Fixed the bug.

In my xml layout I used these code inside of Floating Action Bar for changing this as a desired color.

```
app:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
```

here, I imported

**xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"**

After changing this to,

**xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"**.

It is working nice even in **API 21.**